# Laravel 5.4 Redirect Not Working Correctly for external url

Tags: php, laravel-5, model-view-controller, routes

I have the following __construct() in a Controller (this is simply for testing):

```
public function __construct( ) {

    $this->middleware( 'auth' );

    return redirect('http://www.google.com');

}
```

The application is not redirecting at all to the external URL, instead it just flows through and continues into the method that was called. In desperation I tried it without the return directive, but the same behavior happened. Am I missing something with the redirect call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect::away` will create redirect response to external URL

```
   return Redirect::away('http://www.google.com');
```